# Bindingsource not setting position when using IndexOf

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I have a bindingsource bound to a list of custom objects, and I have the following method:

```
private void SetMyItem(MyItem item)
{
    //Test 1
    if (item != null)
    {
        bsItems.Position = bsItems.List.IndexOf(item);
    }

    //Test 2 
    foreach (var itm in bsItems)
    {
        if (itm.IsEqual(item))
        {
            bsItems.Position = bsItems.List.IndexOf(itm);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The list contains a few items, and one of these is also the parameter passed to the method.

In the first test above, I'm immediately setting the position by getting the index of the passed parameter. The position is -1.

To make sure that the passed parameter is equal to an item in the list, I added the second test. A matching item is found, but the position is still -1.

Why is the binding source not setting the correct position?

**EDIT**

`IsEqual` is an extension method that serializes both objects to a binary stream and compares them.

**EDIT 2**

`IndexOf` is working as expected. It is returning the correct index. However, setting the `Position` to this index is not working.

Comment: What is `IsEqual`?

Comment: The [`IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) method, uses the collection’s objects’ [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`CompareTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx) methods on item to determine whether item exists. Having 2 object which have properties with equal values doesn't mean those objects are equal.

Comment: @RezaAghaei That what I was assuming.

Comment: @RezaAghaei `Equals` actually returns `true` but the position is still -1 after `IndexOf`.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Thats because the IndexOf method is not using your extension method to compare. The IndexOf method will simply check if the object references are the same. It doesnt check the values within the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the only way to get the position to be set correctly is to do:

```
bsItems.ResetBindings(false);
bsItems.Position = bsItems.IndexOf(myItem);
```

Comment: [`ResetBindings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings(v=vs.110).aspx)method causes a control bound to the `BindingSource` to reread all the items in the list and refresh their displayed values.

Comment: Currently, the answer is misleading for future readers. If you think this can be an answer, it's better to share a simple code to reproduce the problem and then show how this recommendation solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreach to be

```
foreach (var itm in bsItems.List)
{
    if (itm.IsEqual(item))
    {
        bsItems.Position = bsItems.List.IndexOf(itm);
        break;
    }
}
```

You are iterating through bsItems but your are trying to find the object in the bsItems.List. They are different.

Comment: Why are they different?

Comment: The are not different. It doesn't matter if you use `BindingSource` or its `List`in a `for` loop. Also `BindingSource.IndexOf` and `BindingSource.List.IndexOf` are completely the same. In fact `BindingSource` uses it's `List` in `IndexOf` or in a `for` loop.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono I dont know. I dont know what your bsItems object is. Can you tell me what the type of bsItems is?

Comment: @CathalMF It's just a POCO class with a some `int` and `string` properties.

Comment: Does my suggestion work? If not please post the class definition in your question.

Comment: @CathalMF No it doesn't. Even `bsItems.Position = bsItems.IndexOf(bsItems[0])` doesn't work. Position is still -1.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Since its a custom object we have no idea whats happening in your object creation and lookup that might be changing the references. You need to post the full definition of your bsItems object.